# Can a verb be made pronominal and keep the meaning of its non-pronominal form as in "Se hacen la compra los unos a los otros"?

Tags: verbos, verbo-pronominal

Can a verb be made pronominal and keep the meaning of its non-pronominal form? For instance, in the following sentence, why does "hacer" keep it's meaning of "to do"?

> Se hacen la compra los unos a los otros. -
> They do one another's shopping.

(The sentence and its translation are from *A New Reference Grammar of Modern Spanish*, 5th edition, by John Butt and Carmen Benjamin.)

Hacer means "to do" or "to make". However, "hacerse" means "to make oneself", "to pretend", "to act, "to become", "to get used to" and "to feel" according to SpanishDicitionary.com.

So, my question is, since it is obvious that in this instance "to do" is intended rather than any of the meanings of "hacerse", can a Spanish verb just be made pronominal if a reflexive meaning is intended?

Comment: guiujuuu! Llegamos a las 9000 preguntas! Che, y qué significa eso? No me gusta el ejemplo del libro, ni siquiera creo que te podemos ayudar porque no tiene sentido la traducción. Yo puedo ‘hacer las compras’. No veo que tenga sentido ‘hacerle la compra *a alguien*’. En todo caso, se diría directamente ‘*comprar* a alguien’. Así que primero que nada, qué es lo que significa en inglés? Así lo traducimos correctamente

Comment: ‘Se *compran entre sí*’? ‘se *truecan*’? ‘los agentes económicos generan transacciones intermedias entre ellos’? Qué quisiste decir?

Comment: @tac, la frase no suena nada extraña, al menos en España. Nada más leerla me vino la imagen de un familiar mío que, en ocasiones, hacía la compra para sus vecinos. Durante la pandemia no ha sido raro encontrar gente que hacía la compra para otros. Y aquellos que querían minimizar el número de veces que visitaban el supermercado podían ponerse de acuerdo con otros para "hacerse la compra unos a otros".

Comment: @aerobiomat No estoy de acuerdo. En la Argentina se dice ‘hacer la**s** compra**s**’, donde ‘las compras’ se interpreta como el acto de ir a comprar. Está en singular, incluso si gramaticalmente está en plural. La traducción al español es confusa, parece que dice que ‘intercambian (bienes o servicios) entre ellos’. Lo correcto es: ‘**hacen las compras** unos **por** los otros’, sin el ‘se’. Porque además, comprar **a** alguien es distinto de comprar **por** alguien. Y si fuera correcta la frase de la pregunta, deberían aclarar que es para España. Porque acá nadie habla así y sólo confunde

Comment: @tac, por eso he especificado que en España "hacer la compra" (en singular) es una frase muy habitual. Yendo al tema en cuestión, "hacer la compra a Pedro" funciona como "hacer un favor a Pedro", igual que muchas otras frases de la forma "hacer x a alguien". Y puestas en modo reflexivo siguen funcionando: "se hacen la permanente las unas a las otras".

Comment: @aerobiomat Ah, está bien. Es bueno saberlo,  gracias

Comment: @tac you asked what it means in English. The quoted translation (They do one another's shopping) means that some days A goes out and does B's shopping, other days B goes out and does A's shopping. Of course the shopping circle might also involve C D and so on. It would not cover the case where A always shopped for B but B, perhaps because of some disability, never shopped for A.

Comment: So how to you express the non-reciprocal nature of it as discussed by Mdewey.? do you just say,''A hace las compras para B''o''Todos hacen las compras para B''?

Comment: @Bluelion7 Así es. Si ‘A hace las compras por/para B’, en general se da a entender que B no hace las compras por A. En general, la fórmula ‘hacer (algo) por/para alguien’ implica que la finalidad es la voluntad ajena. Así, el prójimo no es el objeto de nuestra acción en donde la aplicamos de forma ‘directa’, sino que éste se beneficia por nuestras acciones. Si querés incorporar la estructura, [te recomiendo que practiques esta canción](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-woJGjAqJE8). Hacelo por mí (y por vos también ;) )

Answer (score 5):

As explained in [DPD](https://www.rae.es/dpd/se) in section 1, the use of *se* as a pronoun can have many meanings.

One of them is as part of a **pronominal verb**, which has a different meaning from the verb without pronoun (section 1d, example "dormirse").

Another one (section 1b) is as a direct or indirect object, when the action of the verb applies to the subject (**reflexive** pronoun, example "peinarse") or when the subject is plural and the the action applies to "each other" (**reciprocal** pronoun, example "María y Juan se escriben cartas").

Your example "Se hacen la compra los unos a los otros" is a reciprocal usage of *se*, so it does not change the meaning of the verb.

Answer (score 4):

I do not think that is strictly speaking pronominal. You should interpret *se* as a reflexive being used in a reciprocal sense. Since that may lead to ambiguity (did the writer mean reflexive or reciprocal) they have helpfully added *los unos a los otros* to make it clear a reciprocal usage is intended here.